# Powershell: How can I validate parameters from the command line at input?

Tags: powershell

Ex, suppose I have

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $resourceName
)
```

and I want to validate resourceName right there and see if it is not equal to test. Do i do this using validate script? All examples I see online are doing it in functions, not as part of input

Validate script is not working as expected.

Comment: there are many many parameter declarations to perform different input validations, in this case it seems it would as easy as `[ValidateSet('Test')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validate set will allow values only specified

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('Prod','Dev')]
    [string]$resourceName
)
```